# How to hide fly out menu button and how to navigate to the first page in MAUI

Tags: maui

I developed a wizard control in MAUI whose content page is shown when user clicks an option in the fly out menu. Finally the last step of the wizard looks like this:

[image]

The Wizard page is displayed from the Shell menu, this way (in AppShell.xaml)

```
    <ShellContent
        Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
        Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
        Title="Enrolamiento"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EnrolamientoPage}"
        Route="EnrolamientoPage">
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.User}" Color="Maroon" Size="50"/>
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
```

Please see the 3 lines shown by the red arrow. When wizard page is shown, I need that lines to be hidden (so, user cannot see fly out menu while in the wizard).

When the last step is reached, the "Finalizar" ("Finish") button shows the main page, this way:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MainPage));
```

The problem with that is that when the `MainPage` is shown, the three lines of the fly out menu is replaced by the left arrow, so that user can go back.

How can I go to main page so that user can show the fly out menu instead of going back?

I was trying to get that information but I couldn't.

EDIT:

Here I am register `MainPage` route.

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see the other code of your app, but you can check if you have registered routes for your contentpage (`MainPage`)?  For more information, check: [Register routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-routes).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have edited the question to show you where I am registering.

Comment: I have found how to hide the fly out menu button. I used this programmatically: `Shell.Current.FlyoutBehavior = Welcome.IsVisible ? FlyoutBehavior.Flyout : FlyoutBehavior.Disabled;`, so the button only is shown when the first step of the wizard is visible. I only need to know how to accomplish the second part of que question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, in order to show the flyout menu lines, instead of the back arrow, I only needed to add `//` in front of the route, this way:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
```

For the other problem, I could this this:

```
Shell.Current.FlyoutBehavior = Welcome.IsVisible ? FlyoutBehavior.Flyout : FlyoutBehavior.Disabled;
```